# Converting 8 bit binary to a hexadecimal pair as unsigned char

Tags: string

I have a function:

```
void Epd::SendData(unsigned char data) {
  digitalWrite(dc_pin, HIGH);
  SpiTransfer(data);
}
```

At the moment I am hardcoding data sent to it by calculating on paper and then writing the result as code, but I want to improve that. For example, I am calling:

```
SendData(0x03);
SendData(0x1f);
```

To get those two values (`0x03` and `0x1f`) I am converting the decimal value of `799` to binary: `1100011111` and then adding `0` at the beginning to make sure my binary result is 16 digits long: `0000 0011 0001 1111`. After that, I convert every 4 bits to hexadecimal value and sending them as pairs using the `SendData` function.

I feel like I am almost there, but I don't know how to convert my result to proper type in order to send it to the `SendData` function:

```
void Epd::SendDecAsData(int dec) {
  int binary[16];
  for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    binary[i] = dec % 2;
    dec = dec / 2;
  }

  int dec1 = binary[15] * 8 + binary[14] * 4 + binary[13] * 2 + binary[12];
  int dec2 = binary[11] * 8 + binary[10] * 4 + binary[9] * 2 + binary[8];
  int dec3 = binary[7] * 8 + binary[6] * 4 + binary[5] * 2 + binary[4];
  int dec4 = binary[3] * 8 + binary[2] * 4 + binary[1] * 2 + binary[0];

  String val1 = "0x" + String(dec1, HEX) + String(dec2, HEX);
  String val2 = "0x" + String(dec3, HEX) + String(dec4, HEX);

  SendData(val1); // error because I'm sending `String` instead of `unsigned char`
  SendData(val2);
}
```

I need help converting those strings (`val1`, `val2`) to the right data type, or even better, optimizing this process to get the final result in the right type with less code/computation (probably avoiding conversion to `String`).

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to split a 16-bit `int` into two `unsigned chars` and send them. Why the convoluted conversion to hex? Why not use something like `SendData(dec >> 8); SendData(dec & 0xff);`. It's just binary data, no need to convert.

Comment: @StarCat I just got the existing code (e-ink board) and I see they are sending hex value so I assumed I have to do the same. There is a ton of hardcoded `SendData` that is manually converted from dec to hex (for some reason as two `SendData` calls of 2 digit hex). So even when I just need to send 0 `dec` it is sent as `SendData(0x00)` called twice. I hope that explanation helps

Comment: What you are sending with SendData(0x00) is *not a hex value*. It's just represented in your code text by a hexadecimal value but it is converted to an (unsigned char) binary value during compilation. You can replace all occurences of 0xNN with their decimal value (as long as they're not part of a string) and your program will work exactly the same. Just try it.

Comment: `799`, `0x031f` and `B0000001100010111` are all stored as the same 16 bit binary number ... the differences are only in the source code for human reading ....  compiled code always deals with `0000001100010111` ... your whole conversion program is a waste of resources ... do what @StarCat suggested in the first comment

Comment: Thank you guys. I'll try as soon as I get to the office tomorrow

Comment: `I am hardcoding data sent to it by calculating on paper and then writing the result as code` ... what exactly are you doing here? ... please provide an example of the data involved in the calculation

Comment: @jsotola for example `031f` is `799` which represents the width of the image I'm adding to the e-ink board. The code I'm using says that it needs to be broken into two separate calls of `SendData` but I will try the suggestions above. If that works I can delete sooooo much code :D

Comment: ok, the image width is hard coded ... if same value is used a lot then define something like `width_h` and `width_l` ... otherwise use the code that @StarCat suggested ... the reason that you have to break down 16 bit values is because the data is transmitted in bytes .... check the library, there may be 16 bit transmit function that does it for you

Comment: @jsotola there are a lot of images and each one with values (x, y, width, height) and not easily understandable because they are split as those two SendData commands so I wanted to make it easier to add new images and make the existing ones easier to read + delete a lot of code

Comment: I can indeed send decimal values instead of hexadecimal (mind blown). The board I'm working with can only take 8 bits of data at once so in order to send `799` decimal I first send `3` and then `31` (3*256 + 31). Knowing this I will manage to drastically clean up the code. I will just write a new method that breaks the decimal value I send as a pair of smaller decimal values. Thank you StarCat and jsotola

Answer (score 1):

As [StarCat suggested](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/79606/converting-8-bit-binary-to-a-hexadecimal-pair-as-unsigned-char/79658#comment177213_79606), I can just send decimal values using the same function `SendData` I was provided with. Because the e-ink board can only communicate in 8-bit commands I still had to split my decimal value before sending it.

This is the function I used to send decimal data in 8-bit pairs:

```
void Epd::SendDecAsData(int dec) {
  if (dec == 0) {
    SendData(0);
    SendData(0);
  } else {
    SendData((dec-1) / 256);
    SendData((dec-1) % 256);
  }
}
```